# Inserting into sql-database, reporting success but no rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I'm a uni student who is trying to teach himself C#/.NET (as my stream sadly doesn't teach it) and I've hit a wall when it comes to inserting into an SQL database (I'm using an Sql Server in this example). What is confusing me is that the code is reporting success, but when I inspect the table for data, nothing is there. Here's my code where I try to write to a database:

```
public bool AddStaff(Staff s)
{

    String query = @"INSERT into Staff (firstname, surname, email, phone, notes, status)";
    query +=       @" VALUES (@_firstname, @_surname, @_email, @_phone, @_notes, @_status)";


    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, _db);

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_firstname", s.FirstName);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_surname", s.Surname);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_email", s.Email);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_phone", s.Phone);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_notes", s.Notes);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_status", s.StatusToString());

    int res = 0;

    _db.Open();
    res = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();   // Run the statement.
    _db.Close();

    if (res == 1) return true;           // Should only update one row.
    else return false;
}
```

I've read a few threads on here before posting and I'm using the Parameters because a lot of the examples here used it and because it makes the code more readable. Also, `res` == 1 in the end, implying that one row has been updated.

When I call this method, it's inside a `try/catch` block, no exceptions are caught. What's even more confusing, is that I can do the sql statement raw by right clicking on the database and going 'new query' and it works. I'd appreciate if you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT:

Here's the schema of the relevant table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Staff] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [surname]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [email]     NVARCHAR (75)  NOT NULL,
    [phone]     NVARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
    [notes]     NVARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [status]    NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is your query looks like when you add parameter values? What are your column types?

Comment: How are you verifying the table (SSMS, query in your code, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've added more details about the database table.

Comment: @TTeeple  I'm not sure how to verify the table?

Comment: Lemme rephrase: How are you checking if the record made it to the table?

Comment: @TTeeple I'm going into 'Server Explorer' and right clicking on 'Staff' and selecting 'Show Table Data'. It's empty after my query returns 1 row was affected.

Comment: Since you are a student and is new to this go and have a look at entity Framework. It is very easy to work with

Comment: A couple ideas to check especially if you are using a school database: 1) Have you verified that you have write privileges to this database? Database warnings can seem to not make sense when a security issue is involved; 2) Has auto-commit been disabled in the database? SQL Server is set to auto-commit by default but it can be disabled which would require you to manually commit; 3) Have you verified that your program is disconnecting at the end of the insert? Auto-Commit typically won't complete until the program has finished so a hung process could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I'll bet that you make changes to one database, and look to another database. This is very common mistake. Compare path to database in Server Explorer and connection string in your code.

Comment: @DanK I definitely have write privlidges, I'm just using a local db and can run the insert statement on console no worries. 

I'm not sure about auto-commit, but at the moment, all my select statements are running fine. 

How would I verify my program is disconnecting after an insert? Isn't _db.Close() enough?

Comment: @n4akes You can monitor sessions using the Activity Monitor in SSMS (though you need privileges to view this info). You can check auto-commit setting by going to Tools\Options\Query Execution\SQL Server\ANSI and verifying that SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is unchecked.

Comment: @n4akes Another thing to verify is whether any synonyms exist on the database objects you are using. Synonyms allow you to forego schema declaration but misuse can lead to bizarre problems where you accidentally refer to the wrong copy of the database object. Given that this is a school project (with what I assume is many copies of the staff table on the database), that could very well be your issue. See if you have any better luck with explicit schema declarations in your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally worked out why it isn't working.

The database is being updated in `/bin/Database/model.mdf`. To fix this, I only look at the tables in my Server Explorer that relate to *that* database. I also changed `/Database/model.mdf` property **[copy to output directory]** = `'copy if newer'` from `'always copy'`.

Problem solved. Thank you for all your help and sorry that it was such a petty solution.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows returned by a statement is a unreliable way to check for success. This is subject to session [`SET NOCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) setting.

Simply trust the statement, if it did not throw then the insert succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample based on details you provided. please try to match with this. This worked in my local without any issues.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Staff s = new Staff();

            s.FirstName = "abc";
            s.Surname = "xyz";
            s.Email = "a@a.com";
            s.Phone = "1234";
            s.Notes = "testnotes";

            bool isInserted = AddStaff(s);            
        }

        public static bool AddStaff(Staff s)
        {
            SqlConnection _db = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

            String query = @"INSERT into Staff (firstname, surname, email, phone, notes, status)";
            query += @" VALUES (@_firstname, @_surname, @_email, @_phone, @_notes, @_status)";


            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, _db);

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_firstname", s.FirstName);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_surname", s.Surname);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_email", s.Email);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_phone", s.Phone);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_notes", s.Notes);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_status", s.StatusToString());

            int res = 0;

            _db.Open();
            res = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();   // Run the statement.
            _db.Close();

            if (res == 1) return true;           // Should only update one row.
            else return false;
        }

    }

    class Staff
    {
        private string _firstname;
        private string _surname;
        private string _email;
        private string _phone;
        private string _notes;
        private string _status;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstname;
            }
            set
            {
                _firstname = value;
            }
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get
            {
                return _surname;
            }
            set
            {
                _surname = value;
            }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return _email;
            }
            set
            {
                _email = value;
            }
        }

        public string Phone
        {
            get
            {
                return _phone;
            }
            set
            {
                _phone = value;
            }
        }

        public string Notes
        {
            get
            {
                return _notes;
            }
            set
            {
                _notes = value;
            }
        }

        public string StatusToString()
        {
            return "Valid";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my code pretty much already looks like that, except I've made a Controller class that handles the connection string when you make an instance of the class. That way you can just _db.Open() in any method.